# Two column div layout filling entire height of parent div

Tags: html, css

ok, I believe that this is so common but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere.  Basically I want a two column div layout with the left column being fluid and the right column fixed.  I want the heights of both these columns to fill the parent container div.

Currently, my right div does not fill the 100% of the height and I don't know what's going wrong?

HTML divs are:

```
<div id="nmv_div_twoColumnLayoutContainer">

    <div id="nmv_div_twoColumnLeftContainer">
        <div id="nmv_div_twoColumnLeft">
            <p>the left div is good height</p>
            <p>As this is the div that will typically have the most data</p>
        </div>        
    </div>    
    <div id="nmv_div_twoColumnRightContainer" class="roundedCorners">
        <div id="nmv_div_twoColumnRight">
            the right div is a menu div but is only showing part            
        </div>        
    </div>
    <div class="clearBoth"></div>
</div>
```

And my associated css

```css
.roundedCorners {
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.clearBoth {
    clear: both;
}

div#nmv_div_twoColumnLayoutContainer 
{
    overflow: hidden;
}

div#nmv_div_twoColumnRightContainer 
{
    float: right;   
    margin-left: -250px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: gold;
}

div#nmv_div_twoColumnLeftContainer 
{
    float: left;    
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}

div#nmv_div_twoColumnLeft 
{
    margin: 0 260px 0 0;    
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

div#nmv_div_twoColumnRight 
{    
    width: 250px;
    background-color: green;     
    height: 100%;    
}
```

Comment: `display: table/table-row/table-cell/...`

Comment: @biziclop sorry put the display on where?

Comment: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

Comment: @TheZ but those are all floated columns with %widths.  One of my columns has fixed widths?

Comment: Is the content in your right column variable?  Or will it always be the same height?

Comment: @gilly3 content in the right is variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=css%20tricks%20for%20two%20column%20layouts&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=d7a50cc02f3c90da&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&biw=1366&bih=611) gave me the following links.  These methods are pretty common for doing what you're trying to do.

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/

http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/equal-height-columns/

http://woorkup.com/2009/10/11/really-simple-css-trick-for-equal-height-columns/

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

The basic reason why your code is not working is because the height of an element is calculated differently than you might expect (it's different than width). [This article](http://webdesign.about.com/od/csstutorials/f/set-css-height-100-percent.htm) has a good explanation of how it's calculated.

Answer (score 0):

If the content in your menu is static and you can rely on it staying the same height you can set a `min-height` on your content div to the height of the menu, and position the menu absolutely.  Give the container some right padding so the content doesn't overlap the menu.

```css
.container {
    padding-right: 260px;
    position: relative;
}
.content {
    min-height: 100px;
}
.menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 250px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/Q5CRr/

Comment: cheers.  I don't think the content height will be static but if it is, that sounds like a good option